# How to import \ update data from column from one table to column from another table by comparing their ids

Tags: sql, database, import, compare

I have 2 tables.

1 Table have 2 columns `key` and `id2` (not primary).
2 Table have 2 columns `key` and `id2` (not primary)  and so on information in row that cant be ignored.

How can i import or update `key` from 1st table using smth like : "if 1st table id2= 2nd table id2 then import 1st `key` to `key`? I simply dont understand....

Comment: What you mean: "import"?

Comment: It means get data from column in one table to update or smth in column from other table where no data

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Mysql Myisam database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE dt SET dt.key = st.anotherkey
FROM DestinationTable AS dt INNER JOIN SourceTable AS st ON dt.Key2 = st.Key
```

But before you run above query, try this:

```
SELECT dt.*, st.*
FROM DestinationTable AS dt INNER JOIN SourceTable AS st ON dt.Key2 = st.Key
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer according to what I understand of your question:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET key=Table1.key
WHERE Table1.id2=Table2.id2;
```

Comment: Doesnt work .  #1054 - Unknown column 'top_keys.servername' in 'where clause'   but there are this column! Screenshot : http://gyazo.com/6941164a51b2297e394452dbeb4577fa.png  Code : 
UPDATE `top_servers`
SET `serverkey`=`top_keys`.`serverkey`
WHERE `top_keys`.`servername`=`top_servers`.`linktopid`;

Answer (score 0):

I cant say that im fag , bud i found one varitant of problem :D
So as I bad coder , i decided to make this. Cuz no time to find better solution

```
for i :=0 to files.Count-1 do
begin
key:=parsregexp(Files[i],'\d+,.\d+,.[\x27](\S+)[\x27],.[\x27]');
id:=parsregexp(Files[i],'\d+,.(\d+),.[\x27]\S+[\x27],.[\x27]');

if id<>'FailMe!' then
begin
  for k:=0  to filesnew.Count-1 do
  begin
    id2:=parsregexp(filesnew[k],'\d+,..\S+.,..\S+.,..\S+.,.(\d+),.[\x27]');
    if id2=id then
    begin
       position:=pos(id2,filesnew[k])+6+length(id)+length(id);
       line:= filesnew[k];
       Insert(key, line,position);
       filesnew[k]:=line;
    end;
  end;
end;
end;
```

Yes , ugly , and so sad :D
Maybe to someone it will help. Think different ;)